# Eigenvalues from the relation $2M + I = M^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$$M=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 1  \\
        1 & 2  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

How can we use $2M + I = M^2$ to find the eigenvalues of M.

Comment: This tells you that any eigen-value $\lambda$ must satisfy the equation $2\lambda + 1 = \lambda^2$.

Answer (score 1):

$$det(M - \lambda I) = 0$$
$$ \iff(-\lambda)(2-\lambda) - 1 = 0$$
$$\iff -2\lambda + {\lambda}^2 -1 = 0$$
$$\iff {\lambda}^2 = 2\lambda + 1$$

Notice this is the same as replacing $M$ by $\lambda$ in the relation you wrote.

I'll leave the rest up to you.

---

**Edit**

I've just learned that this is a consequence of the [Cayley-Hamilton Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem).

It states that any square $\left (n \times n \right)$ matrix $A$ satisfies its own characteristic polynomial $p(\lambda)$.

Answer (score 0):

If we are using row vectors, then $\lambda$ is an [eigenvalue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors) if and only if there exists $\vec x\ne\vec 0$ such that
$$\vec x M = \lambda \vec x$$
From this you get:
$\vec x M^2 = \lambda \vec x M = \lambda^2 \vec x$
$\vec x (2M+I) = 2\vec x M + \vec x = 2\lambda\vec x+\vec x = (2\lambda+1)\vec x$
Since we have $(2\lambda+1)\vec x=\lambda^2 \vec x$ for a non-zero vector $\vec x$, we get that
$$2\lambda+1=\lambda^2.$$

---

There is nothing special about the choice of the polynomial in this particular example. To learn more about this, you can read about relation of eigenvalues to [minimal polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_%28linear_algebra%29) and [characteristic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial) of a matrix.